# copyfromrecordset fails with ...object is closed

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

Using SQL Server, MS Office 365 32bit, Windows 7 64bit, I am trying to run a simple SQL query from Excel.  It works but I cannot get it to return the result.

I have tried to find the solution and tried several examples.  I have verified my code runs, it successfully executes the sql on the sqlserver, I just can't get the result back to excel.  Fails with

> Runtime error 3704.

```vb
Sub Clear_Temp_Tables()

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim StrQuery As String

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Data Source=xxxxxxxx\xxxxxx;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=xxxxxxx;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"

    'Opens connection to the database
    cnn.Open

    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    StrQuery = "SELECT * FROM [blah]"

    Set rst = cnn.Execute(StrQuery)

    ' Fails HERE:
    Sheets("Data").Range("O9").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Your query creates a table and then immediately drops the table. It does NOT generate any resultset. So there is nothing to retrieve and therefore nothing to copy into any range.

Comment: Your sql produces no recordset. You need `select`  (not `select .. into` which is effectively `insert`.

Comment: Thank you.  What I'm actually after is to drop a table.  And know if it did it.  I changed the sql to SELECT * FROM dbo.[blah].  Same code returns one record in SSMS.  I get the same error in this VBA though.

Comment: I edited the code above to show the problem.

Comment: Problem is that no Results are received. Check your query in Database

Comment: Thank you.  I was incorrect, it works if it returns one row.